# How to add chain functions from one class to another?

Tags: javascript, function, class

I am trying to develop a game engine for personal use in JS. I want to have my engine be able to use elements of separate classes. One such problem I am trying to solve is chaining methods from one class (say a math class that chains functions) to my main function.

**Here is an example of what I want it to look like:**

```js
let game = new Engine()
game.operator(5).sum(3).divide(2)
```

Here's what it might be in my code, although this is where I am not sure what to do.

```js
class Engine {
   constructor() {
    //Set up engine here
    /* This is where I am unsure how to link the following operator class to this one. 
    * Do I put it here in constructor or ...
    */

   }
   /* ... do I put it here? (Or not in this class at all?)
   *
   * This is what I tried doing as a function
   *
   * operator(input) {
   *    let op = new Operator(input);
   * }
   */
}
class Operator {
    /*The following class is different than the one I am using, but follows similar syntax: 
    * Basic usage: operator(5).sum(3, 4) => Should output 12
    * How the class works is mostly irrelevant, just know it chains methods.
    */
    constructor(input) {
        this.input = input;
        this.answer = this.input;
    }
    sum() {
        let a = arguments[0]
        for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            a += arguments[i];
        }
        this.answer += a;
        return this;
    }
    divide() {
        let a = arguments[0];

        for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            a *= arguments[i];
        }
        this.answer /= a;
        return this;
    }

}
```

How can I get one class to be able to chain methods from different class?

Comment: `operator` function in `Engine` can return the Operator object you built there. It's nice you can chain things in a single statement, but don't overdo it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pattern for chaining is to have the instance keep a chain state, and to provide a 'value' method that returns the chain state. To chain between two classes, I guess I'd include a special value method that returns an instance of the other class. (To keep the reader oriented, name it something that indicates the type change)...

```js
class ObjectA {
  constructor(string) {
    this.chainValue = string
    this.string = string
  }

  transformA() {
    this.chainValue = this.chainValue.toUpperCase()
    return this
  }

  transformB() {
    this.chainValue = this.chainValue + "bar"
    return this
  }

  // the regular value method
  get value() {
    return this.chainValue
  }

  // like the value method, but named to explicitly return MyNumber
  get numberValue() {
    return new MyNumber(this.value.length)
  }
}

class MyNumber {
  constructor(int) {
    this.chainValue = int
    this.int = int
  }
  
  add(n) {
    this.chainValue += n
    return this
  }
  
  get value() {
    return this.chainValue
  }
}

let a = new ObjectA("foo")
console.log(
  a
  .transformB()   // append "bar"
  .transformA()   // convert to upper case
  .numberValue    // return a number (arbitrarily, the length of the chain state)
  .add(12)        // add 12
  .value          // expect 18
)
```

Comment: This also works well! This outputs the same as the other answer but doesn't require proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Proxy for that purpose.

```js
    class Engine {
    operator() {
      // code
      console.log('call operator')
    }
  }
  class Operator {
    sum() {
      // code
      console.log('call sum')
    }

    divide() {
      console.log('call divide')
    }
  }

  class SuperOperator {
    negate() {
      console.log('call negate')
    }
  }

  const operator = new Operator();
  const superOperator = new SuperOperator();
  const engine = new Engine();


  const objectsToChainFrom = [
    engine,
    operator,
    superOperator,
  ];

  // create helper function for proxy
  function wrapper(originalMethod, ctx) {
    return function () {
      originalMethod.apply(ctx, arguments);
      // return proxy;
      return this;
    }
  }

  var proxy1 = new Proxy(objectsToChainFrom, {
    get(target, methodToCall, receiver) {
      const objectWithMethod = target.find(el => el[methodToCall]);
      return wrapper(objectWithMethod[methodToCall], objectWithMethod)
    }
  });

  proxy1
    .sum()
    .operator()
    .divide()
    .negate()
```